# What did Scarlet mean by the line: "Because so many people do?"

Tags: language-explanation, lunar-chronicles

From the book, *[Cress](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13206828-cress)* (2014), by Marissa Meyer:

> Wolf rubbed his temple. “Let’s hope you never have to face off against the
> queen’s real soldiers. I think we stand a chance going up against her
> thaumaturges and special operatives, but the advanced soldiers are different.
> More like animals than humans, and they don’t react well to brain
> manipulation.”
> “Because so many people do?” said Scarlet, scraping her spoon against the
> bowl.
>
> <sub>*Cress* (2014) by Marissa Meyer - Page 17</sub>

I didn’t understand the line: ”Because so many people do?” Because so many people do *what*? Control them? Please explain what Scarlet meant by that.

Comment: "Because so many people `react well to brain manipulation`?"

Comment: @Blaze : sounds like an answer - you should post it

Answer (score 4):

The first speaker is apparently singling out a specific group that "don't react well to brain manipulation".

Scarlet's response is being a bit snide, asking in her tone if the first speaker believes the rest of population *does* react well to having their brains manipulated.